# Invalid hook call error and my login form does not display

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-dom

when I run my project I get this error:

```
Uncaught Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app
See https://reactjs.org/link/invalid-hook-call for tips about how to debug and fix this problem.
    at resolveDispatcher (react.development.js:1476:1)
    at useMemo (react.development.js:1531:1)
    at FormGroup.js:11:1
    at renderWithHooks (react-dom.development.js:14985:1)
    at updateForwardRef (react-dom.development.js:17044:1)
    at beginWork (react-dom.development.js:19098:1)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js:3945:1)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:3994:1)
    at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js:4056:1)
    at beginWork$1 (react-dom.development.js:23964:1)
```

I get mulitple errors for the Button Form Col and Row bootstrap components.

So when I run npm ls react-dom I get this:

```
├─┬ react-bootstrap@2.2.0
│ ├─┬ @restart/ui@1.0.2
│ │ └── react-dom@17.0.2 deduped
│ ├── react-dom@17.0.2
│ └─┬ react-transition-group@4.4.2
│   └── react-dom@17.0.2 deduped
└─┬ react-slideshow-image@3.7.0
  └── react-dom@17.0.2 deduped
```

And when I run npm ls react I get this:

```
├─┬ react-bootstrap@2.2.0
│ ├─┬ @restart/hooks@0.4.5
│ │ └── react@17.0.2 deduped
│ ├─┬ @restart/ui@1.0.2
│ │ ├─┬ @react-aria/ssr@3.1.2
│ │ │ └── react@17.0.2 deduped
│ │ └── react@17.0.2 deduped
│ ├─┬ prop-types-extra@1.1.1
│ │ └── react@17.0.2 deduped
│ ├─┬ react-dom@17.0.2
│ │ └── react@17.0.2 deduped
│ ├─┬ react-transition-group@4.4.2
│ │ └── react@17.0.2 deduped
│ ├── react@17.0.2
│ └─┬ uncontrollable@7.2.1
│   └── react@17.0.2 deduped
├─┬ react-redux@7.2.6
│ └── react@17.0.2 deduped
└─┬ react-slideshow-image@3.7.0
  └── react@17.0.2 deduped
```

Does this mean I have duplicated versions and how do I fix that ? I also do not have any hooks in the code, the code is a bootstrap-react form:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { Form, Button, Row, Col } from "react-bootstrap";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

  function LoginScreen() {
   return (   
       <div className="loginContainer">
           <Form>
           <Form.Group controlId="formBasicEmail">
             <Form.Label>Email address</Form.Label>
             <Form.Control
               type="email"
             />
           </Form.Group>
           <Form.Group controlId="formBasicPassword">
             <Form.Label>Password</Form.Label>
             <Form.Control
              type="password"
               placeholder="Password"
             />
           </Form.Group>
           <Button variant="primary" type="submit">
             Submit
           </Button>
         </Form>
         <Row className="py-3">
           <Col>
             New Customer ? <Link to="/register">Register Here</Link>
           </Col>
         </Row>
       </div>
    
   );
 }
 export default LoginScreen;
```

Comment: It most likely means you have a hook call outside the body of a function component (2). Stuff like `const value = useWhatever(...);` can only be inside the body of a React functional component.

Comment: The error should point you to a specific file and line; the LoginScreen component you posted imports two hooks but doesn't use them.